# how to disable <ENTER> key for form submit in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

In the following snippet, I have a number of input forms that are type text. If the user hits , it seems I am getting the same synthetic event as if they press the submit button. I want to ignore the  as a form submit, and only allow one to press the SUBMIT button. (I deleted some of the Form Groups to cut down on the example).

In all cases (button or ENTER key)

```
e.key is undefined
e.which is undefined
e.type is submit
e.target is the submit button
```

(this is a synthetic event)

```
const React = require('react')
import { Form, FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, Col, Button, Tooltip, OverlayTrigger } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Configuration = ({ ServerPort, UserID, PortNumber, WWWUrl, SourcePath, FMEPath }) => {
    const buttonAction = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(e.target.innerHTML)
    }
    return (
        <Form horizontal>
            <FormGroup controlId="serverPortBox">
                <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>Watson Port:</Col>
                <Col sm={10}>
                    <OverlayTrigger placement="left" overlay={(<Tooltip id="tt1">TCP port for Watson to use</Tooltip>)}>
                        <FormControl type="number" min="1024" max="65535" placeholder={ServerPort} />
                    </OverlayTrigger>
                </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup controlId="dbPortBox">
                <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>Database Port:</Col>
                <Col sm={10}>
                    <OverlayTrigger placement="left" overlay={(<Tooltip id="tt3">TCP port for PostGreSql DB</Tooltip>)}>
                        <FormControl type="number" min="1024" max="65535" placeholder={PortNumber} />
                    </OverlayTrigger>
                </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <Button type="submit" bsStyle="primary" block onClick={(e) => buttonAction(e)}>Update Configuration</Button>
        </Form>
    )
}

export default Configuration
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe should insert button with type *"button"* instead *"submit"*? and then just handle `onClick` for this button?

Comment: This works, but I was hoping to use redux-forms (http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/) and I think they require a type of "submit"

Comment: I think you can use the button type. For example in docs: http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/simple/ i see the button with type button for reset. But i think you can try it for submit button also

Comment: If you run into this issue, I found this issue on github to be very helpful, provides additional insight: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/572#issuecomment-268905929

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution would be to just use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.

Comment: This works, but I was hoping to use redux-forms (http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/) and I think they require a type of "submit"

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library so that might be a topic for another question. In my opinion though, a library shouldn't enforce something like `type="submit"`, especially since the default behavior for `type="submit"` is usually not good UX for modern websites.

Comment: I agree with you about type submit and modern websites

Answer (score 5):

I found solution how to implement this without using `type="button"`

```
const handleKeyDown = (event, callback) => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter' && event.shiftKey === false) {
    event.preventDefault();
    callback(submitAddress);
  }
};
```

and changes in form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitAddress)} onKeyDown={e => { handleKeyDown(e, handleSubmit) }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<Button type="button">...</Button>
```

Change type from **submit** to **button**