# Redux Form Disable Enter button on field Array

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm working on a redux-form field array. I want to get rid of any and fields buttons and have the next field generated onkeyPress 'enter'.  We will be using a scanner to enter the fields and I can code in a return on the scan to render the next field.  Redux form defaults enter too 'submit'.  I have read several online articles about disabling it.  I have followed them and still have the same issue of the 'enter' key going to submit.  I'm open to any ideas on this.

```
class AssignDeviceForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

   FieldArraysForm = props => {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Well>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(() => {})}>
          <FieldArray name="IMEIs" component={this.renderIMEI}/>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
            <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
              Clear Values
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </Well>
      </div>
    );
  };

  renderIMEI = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed } }) => {
    if (fields.length == 0) {
      fields.unshift({});
    }

    return(
    <ul>
      <h3>Scan the devices you want to assign</h3>
      {fields.map((IMEI, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <button
            type="button"
            title="Remove Device"
            onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
          />
          <h4>Device #{index + 1}</h4>
          <Field
            name={`${IMEI}.txtIMEI`}
            type="text"
            component={this.renderField}
            label="IMEI"
            onKeyPress={e => {
              if (e.key === 'Enter') 
              e.preventDefault()
              console.log('WAHOO!!!')
              {this.renderIMEI} 
            }}
          />    
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )};

  renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, active } }) => (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <div>
        <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} />
        {active && touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.FieldArraysForm()}
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: i have found how to implement without adding type="button" https://stackoverflow.com/a/51982595/1648498

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of preventing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key from submitting the form would be utilizing the `onkeypress` event on the `form` like so:

A working (basic) example can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l79999mkq7)

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(() => {})} onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}>
   <FieldArray name="IMEIs" component={this.renderIMEI}/>
   <div>
       <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
       <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Where the `this.onKeyPress` function will check if the <kbd>enter</kbd> key was pressed

```
onKeyPress = (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    event.preventDefault(); //<===== This stops the form from being submitted
    alert("enter")
  } else {
    alert("not enter")
  }
}
```

In the onKeyPress function, you can do whatever you like, please do note that the `event.preventDefault()` is what's stopping the form from being submitted by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to intercept every single key on `onKeyPress`, place the 'onSubmit' button outside the form. Like this

```
<form>
   <FieldArray name="IMEIs" component={this.renderIMEI}/>
</form>
<div>
  <button onClick={()=> doSomething} disabled={submitting}>
    Submit
  </button>
  <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
    Clear Values
  </button>
</div>
```

It might have its own accessibility downsides though

Comment: Could you explain what kind of accessibility downsides this solution might have?

Comment: After my brief research I have found none to be honest but I am not a specialist in accessibility.